# Define a polynomial function in Julia

Tags: function, julia, polynomials

I  want to create the function using `Polynomials` package in Julia, while `c` is a Vector and `n` is the length of the Vector. I can make it in `JuMP` package but not in Polynomials.

[image]

Any idea how to create this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `Polynomial` on this vector `c`.

```
julia> c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> p = Polynomial(c)
Polynomial(1 + 2*x + 3*x^2 + 4*x^3)

julia> c = [2, 4, -8, 0, 0, 1]; 

julia> p = Polynomial(c)
Polynomial(2 + 4*x - 8*x^2 + x^5)

julia> p(2) #evaluate the polynomial at x = 2
10
```